# Using DC to prove well-foundedness criterion

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I've proven DC, namely:

Let $R\subset a \times a$ so that for each $x\in a$ there is some $y\in a$ with $(y,x)\in R$. Then there is some function $f: \omega \rightarrow a$ so that for any $n\in \omega$ we have $(f(n+1), f(n))\in R$.

Now, I want to use this fact to prove that $R\subset B\times B$ is well-founded iff there is no function $f: \omega \rightarrow B$ such that $(f(n+1), f(n))\in R$ for each $n\in \omega$. (By the way, well-foundedness here means each nonempty subset of $B$ has an $R$-least element.)

However, I haven't been able to work out the proof. Am I wrong to use DC for this proof? If not, how would it go?

Comment: How exactly did you prove DC, by the way? From what did you prove it?

Comment: @PatrickStevens ZFC (i.e., with Axiom of choice)

Comment: The easier case is showing that if $R$ is *not* well-founded, then there *is* such a function. Can you do this one? HINT: don't apply DC to $R$ (that doesn't get you anywhere since $R$ doesn't obviously satisfy the hypotheses); instead, can you think of a relation *related* to $R$ in some way, which "points along" a given infinite $R$-sequence?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I see that we can find a subset of $B$ that has no minimal element, so that $R$ restricted to $B$ satisfies the conditions of DC. Could I do anything from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to prove that well-foundedness equivalent to the Principle of Dependent Choice.

So assume that $R$ is a well-founded relation on some non-empty set $B$. If there is an infinite decreasing chain, then clearly $R$ is not well-founded.

The other direction, however, requires that we use Dependent Choice. Suppose that $R$ is not well-founded. Let $A$ be a set without a minimal element, witnessing that $R$ is not well-founded. Define $X$ to be the set of finite sequences of $R$-decreasing sequences from $X$, with $S$ being the end-extension relation on $X$.

Now, using Dependent Choice, we can find an $S$-sequence in $X$. The $S$-sequence's limit is a function from $\omega$ to $B$ as required.